# Jquery AJAX not sending Data on other webpage

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to jQuery and Ajax. I am currently working on a list of table that will filter the information by dates. It's not working then I tried to recreate the same logic I used in a separate file and I found out that the Ajax is sending but the second PHP file is not receiving the data.

This is my first file code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({  
        url:"ech1.php",  
        method: 'POST',  
        data:{
            testing: "testingd"
    },  
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(data)  
        {  
             $( "#resulta" ).html(data);
        }  
         });  
    });
});
```

This is the second file code :

```php
<?php
    echo $_POST['testing'];
?>
```

The 2nd php file should print the word `testingd` from the first PHP file.

but it returns an error :

> Warning: Undefined array key "testing" in C:\xampp\htdocs\trashbin\apis\ech1.php on line 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can get response like example: `response.testing`

Comment: Can you please clarify your setup? Is `echo $_POST['testing'];` in `ech1.php`? Is the AJAX in a different file or the same one?

Comment: Also, in your images two requests are happening. Did you trigger it twice or is another unexpected request taking place?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following on your second file

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); // convert JSON into array
echo $input['testing'];
```

The second parameter in the `json_decode` will make sure that the output will be an array.
Hopefully it works. =)

Comment: Can you add further explanation on the code ?

Comment: JSON isn't being sent in the AJAX request, so it makes no sense to capture input.